# Is it "multi-element" or "multi-elemental"? "Multi-attribute" or "multi-attributed"?

Tags: grammar, suffixes, compounds, compound-adjectives

I've seen both being used, so I'm having a hard time telling which one is correct. Logic dictates that it's supposed to be "multi-elemental" and "multi-attributed," considering we have "multicolored," "multiparous," and "multilateral," so you should use -*adjective*, but then I thought about how we have five-story buildings, three-star restaurants, and the like, in which we have -*noun*, so that threw me for a loop (and it doesn't help that there's an entry for "multielement" in the Merrian-Webster online dictionary).

On a related note, would the answer of this question also apply when *multi-* is replaced by another term, such as *fire-* or *light-* (as in, fire-attributed [or fire-elemental] damage), or is *multi-* a special case?

Below are some examples, for reference. Rather embarrassing ones, I guess, given the lack of context, but they are the situations I have in mind, in any case.

- He suffered multielemental/multielement (multiattribute/multiattributed) damage.
- That is a fire-attribute/attributed spell.
- A multielement/multielemental (multiattribute/multiattributed) sigil. (In other words, a sigil comprised of multiple elements.)

If it helps, the meaning "element" has in the sentences above is the following (taken from the Cambridge Dictionary):

> Earth, air, fire, and water from which people in the past believed everything else was made

And yes, before anyone comments on it, I know that when using "fire," "light," and similar terms, I can just remove *-attribute/attributed* (*-element/elemental*) and use those terms directly as adjectives, but I also want to have the option to use them as compound words.

Comment: I think in the context of having multiple attributes *attribute* is a noun, and *multi-attribute* sounds right to me. You mentioned *multicoloured*, but note that *multicolour* is also a word.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for the input! You're right. I've just confirmed it: most dictionaries have entries for both *multicolour* and *multicoloured*, and their meanings are stated to be literally the same. Lovely. Regarding attributes, I see where you're coming from. Do you think that'd also apply to elements? Moreover, when there's only a single attribute as opposed to multiple ones, as I mentioned in the last paragraph (such as *fire-* or *light-*), would you still consider *attribute* a noun, thus leading to the usage of *-attribute* instead of *-attributed*?

Comment: I think context will matter, but I'm not clear on how you want to use these terms. Can you perhaps [edit] your question to include some full sentence examples?

Comment: @nnnnnn Done. I'm not sure of how much help it'll be, considering they pertain to a very specific domain of fiction, but I was hoping a parallel could be drawn between them and the grammar rules regarding the structure of compound words.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the lack of context does not help, however,

OED:

> **Elemental, B.** *noun*. **An entity or a force which is regarded by occultists as capable of producing physical manifestations.**
>
> 1894   H. Nisbet Bush Girl's Romance 235   *So that we may not be horrified or shy aside at the sight of the strange beings and elementals that surround us.*

Since the definition was written in 1891, the term has often been used in horror stories and the like – **An elemental** is basically a supernatural and invisible intelligence that can cause things to happen in the real world[1], e.g. make tables move, cause wind to blow, turn on electrical appliances, create the spirits of demons, ghosts of the dead and living, etc.

To avoid misunderstandings, I would not therefore use “elemental” in your context if the story were concerned with “magic” in general unless it were connected to such supernatural beings.

[1] allegedly